# How to clear memory after file_get_contents executes in php

Tags: php, php-5.5

I am trying to add certain variables to couple of files which already have some content.

I am using file_get_contents to copy the contents of a particular file and then using file_put_contents to paste variable values along with the existing contents to that file.

The problem is that, on the first instance it works properly but to the second file it pastes everything that has been stored in the memory. It puts all the contents from the first file along with the contents of the second file.

Is there any way that I can clear the memory before the next file_get_contents executes. Or my concept is false here.

Here is my code...

```
<?php

 if ($_POST["submit"]) {

    $ip = $_POST['ip'];
    $subnet = $_POST['subnet'];
    $gateway = $_POST['gateway'];
    $hostname = $_POST['hostname'];
    $domain = $_POST['domain'];
    $netbios = $_POST['netbios'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    $ipfile = 'one.txt';

    $file = fopen($ipfile, "r");
    $ipfileContents = fread($file, filesize($ipfile));

    $ipcontent = "ip='$ip'\n";
    $ipcontent .= "netmask='$subnet'\n";
    $ipcontent .= "gw='$gateway'\n";
    $conten = $ipcontent . $ipfileContents;

    $file = fopen($ipfile, "w");
    fwrite($file, $ipfileContents);

    fclose($file);

    $ipsh = shell_exec('sh path/to/CHANGE_IP.sh');



    $hostfile = 'two.txt';

    $fileh = fopen($hostfile, "r");
    $hostfileContents = fread($fileh, filesize($hostfile));

    $hostcontent = "ip='$ip'\n";
    $hostcontent .= "m_name='$hostname'\n";
    $hostcontent .= "fqdn='$domain'\n";
    $conten = $hostcontent . $hostfileContents;

    $fileh = fopen($hostfile, "w");
    fwrite($fileh, $hostfileContents);

    fclose($fileh);

$hostsh = shell_exec('sh path/to/MODIFY_HOSTS.sh');


}








?>
```

I have tried unset, but didn't work

```
$ipfilecontents->__destruct();
unset($ipfilecontents);
```

**UPDATE:**

`file_get_contents` & `file_put_contents` has some concurrency problems. So I had to change my method to `fopen/fwrite/fclose` and it worked flawlessly. Thanks for your help Jacinto.

Comment: generally by using `unset`

Comment: yes I have tried using $ipfilecontents->__destruct(); unset($ipfilecontents); but didn't work @MarkBaker

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about it. There's something else going on, but I'm not catching it...

Comment: I don't know...It looks fine to me @PeterBowers

Comment: Have you done an `echo` of `$ipfileContents` and `$hostfileContents` with appropriate === dividers in between?

Comment: Is this for logging? A better option would be to append new logs to a file using `fopen` and `fwrite`. That way you don't have to read the file into memory at all. This will append the new data to the end of the file though, but actually that's how it usually works.

Comment: Make sure you re-start one.txt and two.txt with new content...

Comment: No..This is actually going to different shell script files...and the data needs to be on top of the file. Simply its storing values as varibles which will be callng by a function.@GolezTrol

Comment: `file_put_contents` does also have an append mode. And if you need to lock the file, use `fopen` instead.

Comment: I have tried the append mode with lock_ex... but then it stores the contents to the end of the file. But I want to have the contents on top of the file. @Gumbo

Comment: Try commenting out your `shell_exec()` call in case that's doing something weird...

Comment: What kind of data do you have in one.txt and two.txt? shell commands?

Comment: that file doesnt exist.. but I am going to try with commenting it. @PeterBowers

Comment: Yes. Those are as of now test files. The originals will be .sh files. @PeterBowers

Comment: commenting `shell_exec()` didn't work either. @PeterBowers

Comment: Have you confirmed the content of the 2 files (brief, unique) and checked it via `echo` immediately after reading?

Comment: haveyou try to do, instead of file_gets_content, use fopen and fread.
after write with fwrite. if u want i can show you an example

Comment: For the test.. the two files are blank... and when I run the php file...it first puts relevant values to the one.txt and in two.txt it ofcourse puts the relevent values but also puts the contents of one.txt. Hope I made myself clear. @PeterBowers

Comment: NO I haven't tried that... But doing this way will it write the content to the top of the page. Because that's my primary requirement. If yes, I would request you to show me an example. Thanks @Jacinto

Comment: echo? You're assuming the problem is coming from `file_put_contents` and I'm pretty certain you will find that your variables do not contain what you think they contain... Please try the echo trace. You should check all 4 vars - 2 each before each file_put_contents.

Comment: Is your code exactly copy/pasted in above? Or slightly edited?

Comment: I am not correctly getting the eco trace part...can you please show me an example of what to run @PeterBowers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        if ($_POST["submit"]) {

        $ip = $_POST['ip'];
        $subnet = $_POST['subnet'];
        $gateway = $_POST['gateway'];
        $hostname = $_POST['hostname'];
        $domain = $_POST['domain'];
        $netbios = $_POST['netbios'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];


        $ipfile = 'one.txt';

        $file = fopen($ipfile, "r");
        $ipfileContents = fread($file, filesize($ipfile));

        $ipcontent = "ip='$ip'\n";
        $ipcontent .= "netmask='$subnet'\n";
        $ipcontent .= "gw='$gateway'\n";
        $content = $ipcontent . $ipfileContents;

        $file = fopen($ipfile, "w");
        fwrite($file, $content);

        fclose($file);

        $ipsh = shell_exec('sh path/to/CHANGE_IP.sh');

//do the same to the next file
}
```

Comment: `Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /home1/pramir/public_html/development/samba/new/test.php on line 17`

`Warning: fread(): 4 is not a valid stream resource in /home1/pramir/public_html/development/samba/new/test.php on line 36`

Comment: sory, in the fread, i forgot to change the variable $statusLocation.
Change that for $ipfile. And in the fwrite($file, $content). too

Comment: After adding your code...it now adds nothing to the files. I have added the new code to my question... please see if I am missing anything. Thanks.

Comment: @PeeJay $content= $ipcontent . $ipfileContents;
fwrite($file, $content );
change these two

Comment: Yes..it worked.... Atlast.... you won't believe I was trying this fr the last 4 hours using `file_get_contents` & `file_put_contents`..... Thank You!!!

I believe I can follow the same code for all the files now.

Comment: Had to down vote as the answer is not clearly stating what the fix was... had to go and compare code to see what was different. Amend the above and add the changed line

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer - I'll delete it in a minute. It's just a convenient place to show how to do trace statements:

```
    $ipfile = 'one.txt';
    $ipfileContents = file_get_contents($ipfile);
    $ipcontent = "ip='$ip'\n";
    $ipcontent .= "netmask='$subnet'\n";
    $ipcontent .= "gw='$gateway'\n";
    echo "DEBUG: hostcontent=<pre>$ipcontent</pre><br />====<br />hostfileContents=<pre>$ipfileContents</pre><br />\n";            
    file_put_contents($ipfile, $ipcontent . $ipfileContents,  LOCK_EX);
    $ipsh = shell_exec('sh path/to/CHANGE_IP.sh');

    $hostfile = 'two.txt';
    $hostfileContents = file_get_contents($hostfile);
    $hostcontent = "ip='$ip'\n";
    $hostcontent .= "m_name='$hostname'\n";
    $hostcontent .= "fqdn='$domain'\n";
    echo "DEBUG: hostcontent=<pre>$hostcontent</pre><br />====<br />hostfileContents=<pre>$hostfileContents</pre><br />\n";
    file_put_contents($hostfile, $hostcontent . $hostfileContents,  LOCK_EX);
    $hostsh = shell_exec('sh path/to/MODIFY_HOSTS.sh');
```

Comment: Thanks... I will try this now... You can certainly delete it... but I would request you to keep it for future references.

Comment: You may find that your form is delivering some strange values in $domain...  Do the contents of $ipcontent get put before or after $hostcontent?

Comment: This is the output....

`DEBUG: hostcontent=
ip='180.151.2.164'
netmask='255.255.255.0'
gw='192.168.0.1'

====
hostfileContents=

DEBUG: hostcontent=
ip='180.151.2.164'
m_name='hello'
fqdn='fibromixer.com'

====
hostfileContents=`

Comment: OK, I surrender - I'm still pretty mystified but I can't see anything else that could cause this... I'd recommend going with the fopen/fwrite/fclose that has been suggested and answered here - if that solves the problem then it must be something weird with file_put_contents.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient would be to read and write the file in chunks simultaneously:

- open the file in read-write mode
- read the data chunk that will be overwritten by the new data
- reset pointer to begin of read chunk
- write new data
- make the read data the new data to be written
- repeat until there is no data to write

Example:

```
$bufw = "ip=''\n";
$bufw .= "netmask=''\n";
$bufw .= "gw=''\n";

$bufw_len = strlen($bufw);

$file = fopen($ipfile, 'c+');
while ($bufw_len > 0) {
    // read next chunk
    $bufr = fread($file, $bufw_len);
    $bufr_len = strlen($bufr);

    // reset pointer to begin of chunk
    fseek($file, -$bufr_len, SEEK_CUR);

    // write previous chunk
    fwrite($file, $bufw);

    // update variables
    $bufw = $bufr;
    $bufw_len = strlen($bufw);
}
fclose($file);
```

With this the total memory usage is only up to the length of the new data to be written.

You can make it a function like:

```
function file_prepend_contents($filename, $data, $flags = 0, $context = null) {
    if (!is_null($context)) {
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'c+', ($flags & FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH) === FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH, $context);
    } else {
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'c+', ($flags & FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH) === FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
    }

    if (!$handle) return false;

    if (($flags & LOCK_EX) === LOCK_EX) {
        flock($handle, LOCK_EX);
    }

    $bytes_written = 0;

    $bufw = $data;
    $bufw_len = strlen($bufw);
    while ($bufw_len > 0) {
        // read next chunk
        $bufr = fread($handle, $bufw_len);
        $bufr_len = strlen($bufr);

        // reset pointer
        fseek($handle, -$bufr_len, SEEK_CUR);

        // write current chunk
        if (ftell($handle) === 0) {
            $bytes_written = fwrite($handle, $bufw);
        } else {
            fwrite($handle, $bufw);
        }

        // update variables
        $bufw = $bufr;
        $bufw_len = strlen($bufw);
    }
    fclose($handle);

    return $bytes_written;
}
```